# How to return select text in dropdown using reactjs

Tags: javascript, select, reactjs, dropdown

Can someone help me how to get the text (not the value) of a select dropdown? My dropdown:

```
<select ref="time_select">
    <option value="00:00">12:00am</option>
    <option value="00:30">12:30am</option>
    <option value="1:00">1:00am</option>
    <option value="1:30">1:30am</option>
</select>
```

I can return the value by doing:

`this.refs.time_select.value`

but I want the text between the `> .. <`

I tried

`this.refs.time_select.text`

and

`this.refs.time_select.selected`

but these do not work.. can someone help?

Thanks in advance!